# How is rotatory kinetic energy transformed into electrical energy in a generator?

Tags: energy

I have recently been wondering how a generator, specifically in hydropower plants, transforms rotatory kinetic energy into electrical energy.  I would love to understand how that conversion works inside, what occurs inside a generator to do so? I have looked up in internet but found very little to **how** inside that generator manages to do such conversion. I have always found "the generators transforms rotatory kinetic energy into electric" but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a coil of conducting wire is in a fluxing magnetic field, it will produce electricity. So moving a coil of wire near a magnet, or moving a magnet near a coil of wire will create electric potential between the ends of the coil. Most mechanical generators have an armature with coils of wire on it that is forced to rotate in a magnetic field which can be from permanent magnets or, most commonly, electromagnets called field coils. Some generators may be set up differently, but basically the kinetic energy used to force a coil of wire and  a magnetic field to move, relative to each other, is converted to electrical energy.